# After using Docker-machine to reconfigure docker client how do I set it back to Docker for Windows hyperv

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am currently using **Docker Desktop for Windows** (beta channel) to run hype-v Windows and Linux containers.

I sort of expected that `docker-machine ls` would report a machines created. It doesn't and that may be ok

If I use docker-machine to create a Digital Ocean docker box. I can than reconfigure my docker client to hook up to the remote Digital Ocean docker box.

How do I set the docker client back to the original mapping that "Docker Desktop for Windows" set?

Normally with dock-machine you can do something like:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```